# Checking whether a member is in instance or in prototype

Tags: javascript

When using the `in` keyword, one can easily check whether a given key exists within an object. However, prototype functions are also `in` an object. For example,

```
var arr = {'a': 'foo', 'b': 'bar'}
Object.prototype.dummyfunc = function() {}
'a' in arr // true
'dummyfunc' in arr // true
```

How can I distinguish between a member being really in the instance of the object, or being a prototype function of `Object`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [a method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) for it.

```
obj.hasOwnProperty('foo')
```

Comment: I think you mean 'a' instead of 'foo'.

Comment: @Box9: That's true indeed, didn't notice that as I didn't copy-paste it.

Comment: @Box9: I'd imagine any programmer can figure out what I mean by 'foo' there. And the documentation link was the main point anyways.

Comment: Sure, I just thought it might be confusing since the example in the question explicitly had 'foo' as a value ;)